# why gunicorn use same thread

Tags: python, multithreading, gunicorn

a simple python name myapp.py:

```
import threading
import os

def app(environ, start_response):
    tid = threading.get_ident()
    pid = os.getpid()
    ppid = os.getppid()
    
    # #####
    print('tid ================ ', tid) # why same tid?
    # #####
    print('pid', pid) # 
    print('ppid', ppid) # 

    data = b"Hello, World!\n"
    start_response("200 OK", [
        ("Content-Type", "text/plain"),
        ("Content-Length", str(len(data)))
    ])
    return iter([data])
```

And I start with gunicorn:
gunicorn -w 4 myapp:app

```
[2022-03-28 21:59:57 +0800] [55107] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-03-28 21:59:57 +0800] [55107] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (55107)
[2022-03-28 21:59:57 +0800] [55107] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-03-28 21:59:57 +0800] [55110] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 55110
[2022-03-28 21:59:57 +0800] [55111] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 55111
[2022-03-28 21:59:57 +0800] [55112] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 55112
[2022-03-28 21:59:57 +0800] [55113] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 55113
```

then I curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (or use a browser). logs below:

```
tid ================  4455738816
pid 55112
ppid 55107
tid ================  4455738816
pid 55111
ppid 55107
tid ================  4455738816
pid 55113
ppid 55107
```

the question is **why the tid is same but the pid is not same**.

ps: the code is from https://gunicorn.org/ homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gunicorn creates multiple processes to avoid the Python GIL. Each process has a unique PID.

---

Regarding the threads,
[`threading.get_ident()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.get_ident) is a Python specific thread identifier, it should be regarded as meaningless and relevant only within the local process.

Instead, you should use [`threading.get_native_id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.get_native_id) which returns the unique system-wide thread identifier.

Keep in mind the latter may be recycled and reused upon thread closure.

Comment: yes. your are right. when using get_native_id, it logs:

native_tid 987
native_tid 986
native_tid 985
native_tid 986

Comment: @mleylx I'm glad I could help. If my solution has solved your problem, please be free to click the checkmark next to it and [accept it as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). This lets other users know that your question was solved and awards us both a reputation bonus.